# Linq query select by timespan less then "x"

Tags: c#, linq

How do I select records that have a computed column of type Timespan where I want to select only records with a Timespan greater then a certain amount?

```
MyRecords.Where(e=>e.Hours>0)
```

Where **Hours** is computed from subtracting **starttime** column from **endtime** column.
The above code returns:

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan?' and 'int'

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly compare a TimeSpan object to int, you need to use one of the properties on TimeSpan: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx

For example `MyRecords.Where( e => e.Hours.HasValue && e.Hours.Value.Milliseconds > 0)`

`e.Hours.HasValue` and `e.Hours.Value` are needed because e is actually of type `TimeSpan?` which is a nullable type

I would recommend renaming your computed column `e.Hours` to something more descriptive as it is representing a `TimeSpan?` not just some hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MyRecords.Where(e=>e.Hours != null && e.Hours.Value.Milliseconds > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
MyRecords.Where(e => e.Hours.HasValue && e.Hours.Value.Hours > 0);
```